# Passing order-dependent array into ActiveRecord's find() method

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

### Simple statement of the problem:

The ActiveRecord documentation shows that you can pass several values into the object `find()` method, as follows:

`Person.find(1, 2, 6) # returns an array for objects with IDs in (1, 2, 6)`

My issue is that the objects returned are *insensitive* to the order of the values you pass in.

For instance, `Person.find(1, 2, 6)` returns exactly the same thing as `Person.find(6, 1, 2)`.

Is there any way to make this kind of search order *sensitive*?

It feels like there should be a way to pass in an array of `id` and get an array of `Person` objects back in the same order...

### Broader context, for those interested in reading on:

Really what I'm looking to do more generally, is find the "most viewed" `Person` objects for a given time period.

Here's what I've got:

```
@most_viewed = View.where('created_at < ?', Time.now - 1.week).group(:person_id).order('count_person_id desc').count('person_id').keys
```

This returns an (ordered!) array of `id` values for `Person` objects, in descending order of number of `Views` each `Person` has received in the last week.

My thinking was, if I could pass this array of `id`s into the `Person.find` method, then I'm home free! But maybe there's another way entirely to do it more easily. I'm open to all thoughts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning `ids` from your query you can return the `views` itself.

```
@most_viewed = View.where('created_at < ?', Time.now - 1.week)
  .group(:person_id).order('count_person_id desc').includes(:person)
```

Now you have the persons ordered, but you just have to access them through `@most_viewed` variable.

```
@most_viewed.each do |view|
  # do something with view.person
end
```

**Edit:**

If the solution above is not working for you, you can order the persons in this way

```
Person.find([6, 1, 2]).index_by(&:id).slice(*[6, 1, 2]).values
```

But the order is happening in ruby, not in the query.

Comment: I think there's something funny in the syntax of your first suggestion. For one thing, ruby doesn't have access to the `count_person_id` value until you add the `count(:person_id)` command. Also, it's `include` rather than `includes`. But also I'm getting an exception when I use `include` which is `NoMethodError: undefined method 'include' for #<ActiveSupport::OrderedHash:0x007fcb31273cc0>`.